# Receiving "Error: Provided address "undefined" is invalid" - Decentragram

Tags: solidity, truffle

I apologize in advance if this is a newbie question. I am very new to coding and am working hard to complete my first project. I am following the Decentragram tutorial from Dappuniversity and getting an error with my code. The error is "Error: Provided address "undefined" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted." I am on solidity ^0.5.0 and using truffle 5.1.39. The code is below. I have been searching for an answer, but I am afraid I am too new to understand where I am messing up. Any information is greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Code for Decentragram.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Decentragram {
  string public name = "Decentragram";

  // Store Images
  uint public imageCount = 0;
  mapping(uint => Image) public images;

  struct Image {
    uint id;
    string hash;
    string description;
    uint tipAmount;
    address payable author;
  }

  event ImageCreated(
    uint id,
    string hash,
    string description,
    uint tipAmount,
    address payable author
  );

  event ImageTipped(
    uint id,
    string hash,
    string description,
    uint tipAmount,
    address payable author
  );

  // Create Images
  function uploadImage(string memory _imgHash, string memory _description) public {

    // Make sure Image Description exists
    require(bytes(_description).length > 0);

    // Make sure Image hash exists
    require(bytes(_imgHash).length > 0);

    // Make sure uploader address exists
    require(msg.sender != address(0));


    //Increment Image ID
    imageCount ++;

    // Add Image to Contract
    images[imageCount] = Image(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, msg.sender);

    // Trigger an event
    emit ImageCreated(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, msg.sender);
  }

  // Tip Images
  function tipImageOwner (uint _id) public payable {
    //Make sure the ID is valid
    require(_id > 0 && _id <= imageCount);
    // Fetch the image 
    Image memory _image = images[_id];
    //Fetch the author
    address payable _author = _image.author;

    // Pay the author by sending them Ether
    address(_author).transfer(msg.value); 

    // Increment the tip amount
    _image.tipAmount = _image.tipAmount + msg.value;
    // Update the Image
    images[_id] = _image;
    //Trigger an event
    emit ImageTipped(_id, _image.hash, _image.description, _image.tipAmount, _author);
  }
}
```

Test.js Code below:

```
const Decentragram = artifacts.require('./Decentragram.sol')

require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .should()

contract('Decentragram', ([deployer, author, tipper]) => {
    let decentragram

  before(async () => {
    decentragram = await Decentragram.deployed()
  })

  describe('deployment', async () => {
    it('deploys successfully', async () => {
      const address = await decentragram.address
      assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)
      assert.notEqual(address, '')
      assert.notEqual(address, null)
      assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
    })

    it('has a name', async () => {
      const name = await decentragram.name()
      assert.equal(name, 'Decentragram')
    })
  })

  describe('images', async () => {
    let result, imageCount
    const hash = 'abc123'

    before(async () => {
    result = await decentragram.uploadImage(hash, 'Image description', { from: author })
    imageCount = await decentragram.imageCount()
  })


  it('creates images', async() => {
          // Succes
    assert.equal(imageCount, 1)
    console.log(result)

    //FAILURE: Image must have hash
    await decentragram.uploadImage('', 'Image description', { from: author}).should.be.rejected;

    //FAILURE: Image must have description
    await decentragram.uploadImage('Image hash', '', { from: author}).should.be.rejected;
  })
        // check from Struct
    it('lists images', async() => { 
      const image = await decentragram.images(imageCount)     
      assert.equal(image.id.toNumber(), imageCount.toNumber(), 'is is correct')
      assert.equal(image.hash, hash, 'Hash is correct')
      assert.equal(image.description, 'Image description', 'description is correct')
      assert.equal(image.tipAmount, '0', 'tip amount is correct')
      assert.equal(image.author, author, 'author is correct')})
    
    it('allows users to tip images', async() => {
      //Track the author balance before purchase
      let oldAuthorBalance
      oldAuthorBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(oldAuthorBalance)
      oldAuthorBalance = new web3.utils.BN(oldAuthorBalance)

      result = await decentragram.tipImageOwner(imageCount, { from: tipper, value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'Ether') })

      //SUCCESS
      const event = result.logs[0].args
      assert.equal(event.id.toNumber(), imageCount.toNumber(), 'id is correct')
      assert.equal(event.hash, hash, 'Hash is correct')
      assert.equal(event.description, 'Image description', 'description is correct')
      assert.equal(event.tipAmount, ' 1000000000000000000', 'tip amount is correct')
      assert.equal(event.author, author, 'author is correct')

      //Check that author recieved funds
      let newAuthorBalance 
      newAuthorBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(author)
      newAuthorBalance = new web3.utils.BN(newAuthorBalance)

      let tipImageOwner
      tipImageOwner = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'Ether')
      tipImageOwner = new web3.utils.BN(tipImageOwner)

      const expectedBalance = oldAuthorBalance.add(tipImageOwner)

      assert.equal(newAuthorBalance.toString(), expectedBalance.toString())

      //Failure: Tries to tip a image that does not exist
      await decentragram.tipImageOwner(99, { from: tipper, value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'Ether')}).should.be.rejected;
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using to call whats failing

Comment: the function tipImageOwner is the one that is failing. The test "allows users to tip images"  apologies for not including that

Comment: I think you are never assigning value to tipper, thats why is undefined

Comment: He does though if you look at the top describe block.

Comment: Without a stack trace it is hard to tell(so you should post the stack trace) but are you sure that the value is being set for `_author`?  Does this code work and the test fails or the code doesn't work either?